# How to implement google map javascript api integrate with reactjs?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, reactjs

With reactjs i'm able to display normal map without any extra functionalities. But if i'm trying to add any extra components like "Place search box", it won't work my code. its throwing an error ("SearchBox Undefined"). Is there any way to do this integration part?

Here is my code,

```
var DirectionMap = React.createClass({
  getDefaultProps: function () {
      return {
          initialZoom: 8,
          mapCenterLat: 43.6425569,
          mapCenterLng: -79.4073126,
      };
  },
  componentDidMount: function (rootNode) {
      var mapOptions = {
          center: this.mapCenterLatLng(),
          zoom: this.props.initialZoom
      },
      map = new google.maps.Map(this.getDOMNode(), mapOptions);
      // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
      var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
      var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
      map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
      var markers = [];
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: this.mapCenterLatLng(), title: 'Hi', map: map});
      searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
        var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

        if (places.length == 0) {
          return;
        }
        markers.forEach(function(marker) {
          marker.setMap(null);
        });
        markers = [];
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        places.forEach(function(place) {
        var icon = {
          url: place.icon,
          size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
          origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
          scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
        };

        // Create a marker for each place.
        markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          icon: icon,
          title: place.name,
          position: place.geometry.location
        }));

        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
          // Only geocodes have viewport.
          bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
          bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
        }
      });
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
      });
      this.setState({map: map});
  },
  mapCenterLatLng: function () {
      var props = this.props;
      return new google.maps.LatLng(props.mapCenterLat, props.mapCenterLng);
  },
  render: function () {
      return (
        <div className="embed-item-elem">
          <input id="pac-input" className="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box" />
        </div>
      );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This line looks invalid to me:

```
return (
        <div className="embed-item-elem">
          <input id="pac-input" className="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box" />
        </div>
      );
```

Shouldn't you be treating that as a string of HTML, i.e.

```
return ('
        <div className="embed-item-elem">
          <input id="pac-input" className="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box" />
        </div>
      ');
```